# Consistent width for geom_bar in the event of missing data

Tags: r, ggplot2

Is there a way to set a constant width for `geom_bar()` in the event of missing data in the time series example below?  I've tried setting `width` in `aes()` with no luck. Compare May '11 to June '11 width of bars in the plot below the code example.

```
colours <- c("#FF0000", "#33CC33", "#CCCCCC", "#FFA500", "#000000" )
iris$Month <- rep(seq(from=as.Date("2011-01-01"), to=as.Date("2011-10-01"), by="month"), 15)

colours <- c("#FF0000", "#33CC33", "#CCCCCC", "#FFA500", "#000000" )
iris$Month <- rep(seq(from=as.Date("2011-01-01"), to=as.Date("2011-10-01"), by="month"), 15)
d<-aggregate(iris$Sepal.Length, by=list(iris$Month, iris$Species), sum)
d$quota<-seq(from=2000, to=60000, by=2000)
colnames(d) <- c("Month", "Species", "Sepal.Width", "Quota")
d$Sepal.Width<-d$Sepal.Width * 1000
g1 <- ggplot(data=d, aes(x=Month, y=Quota, color="Quota")) + geom_line(size=1)
g1 + geom_bar(data=d[c(-1:-5),], aes(x=Month, y=Sepal.Width, width=10, group=Species, fill=Species), stat="identity", position="dodge") + scale_fill_manual(values=colours)
```

[image: plot]

Comment: There is a similar issue [here](https://github.com/hadley/ggplot2/issues/235) however it is dealing only with `stats` that cannot handle the width parameter.  `position='dodge'` seems to have the same failing. Someone with a bit more `ggplot` knowledge may want to weight in, but this sounds like a potential bug.

Comment: I came across that issue as well. Good to know. For now, I'll use the workaround posted below by filling in values with NA.

Comment: In his reply to https://github.com/tidyverse/ggplot2/issues/1776, Hadley says: _That's how dodging works. You might want to try facetting instead._ BTW, this issue has been adressed already several times on SO: [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12806260/3817004) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/15367762/3817004), e.g.

Comment: Because the google tends to bring us here when we search for ``geom_bar +width +fixed``, I would like to point out this rather little known trick: ``geom_bar(position = position_dodge(preserve = "single"))``

Comment: There is a [new dodging algorihm](https://github.com/tidyverse/ggplot2/commit/6c91c1d3a835e952b0da97f9117fc760aa162819) in ggplot. The current release (2.2.1 Nov-2017) does not yet contain it.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

The easiest way is to supplement your data set so that every combination is present, even if it has `NA` as its value.  Taking a simpler example (as yours has a lot of unneeded features):

```
dat <- data.frame(a=rep(LETTERS[1:3],3),
                  b=rep(letters[1:3],each=3),
                  v=1:9)[-2,]

ggplot(dat, aes(x=a, y=v, colour=b)) +
  geom_bar(aes(fill=b), stat="identity", position="dodge")
```

[image]

This shows the behavior you are trying to avoid: in group "B", there is no group "a", so the bars are wider.  Supplement `dat` with a dataframe with all the combinations of `a` and `b`:

```
dat.all <- rbind(dat, cbind(expand.grid(a=levels(dat$a), b=levels(dat$b)), v=NA))

ggplot(dat.all, aes(x=a, y=v, colour=b)) +
  geom_bar(aes(fill=b), stat="identity", position="dodge")
```

[image]

Comment: I get the same problem when using boxplot, but this approach by padding with NA does not fix my unequal width boxes problem. The NAs are just dropped.  Padding with 0 appears to work, but then that makes for a mighty ugly plot that includes inappropriate data.  Any suggestions?

Comment: @EtienneLow-Décarie Not offhand. Ask it as a new question (reference this one and show how it doesn't work for boxplots) and maybe someone else can help.

Comment: A note for future users: when applying this solution, be super careful about data types (factors and numerics), otherwise the solution may seem to be "broken" (see the upvoted comment by @EtienneLow-Décarie above). Check [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28890227/control-column-widths-in-a-ggplot2-graph-with-a-series-and-inconsistent-data) for details.

Comment: Honestly I don't think changing the data set for making a graph look nice is a good idea. ggplot should do better with missing observations.

Comment: I found the solution really well done until I didn't realized that what if GREEN will be the NA value and not the RED? in this case, aplying NA values, I have just a emply space between colums, my bars are not "stacked" anymore. Is there some sollution for this? thank!

Comment: Keeping in mind the valid comments of @JustynaS. and @maycca, the only solution that doesn't mess with the dataset or require much additional work (though will still be quite an eyesore) is to use `facet_wrap` or `facet_grid` on the `month` variable -- it will create the three species such that all bar widths across the grid/facets will be equal

Answer (score 48):

Some new options for `position_dodge()` and the new `position_dodge2()`, introduced in **ggplot2 3.0.0** can help.

You can use `preserve = "single"` in `position_dodge()` to base the widths off a single element, so the widths of all bars will be the same.

```
ggplot(data = d, aes(x = Month, y = Quota, color = "Quota")) + 
     geom_line(size = 1) + 
     geom_col(data = d[c(-1:-5),], aes(y = Sepal.Width, fill = Species), 
              position = position_dodge(preserve = "single") ) + 
     scale_fill_manual(values = colours)
```

[image]

Using `position_dodge2()` changes the way things are centered, centering each set of bars at each x axis location.  It has some `padding` built in, so use `padding = 0` to remove.

```
ggplot(data = d, aes(x = Month, y = Quota, color = "Quota")) + 
     geom_line(size = 1) + 
     geom_col(data = d[c(-1:-5),], aes(y = Sepal.Width, fill = Species), 
              position = position_dodge2(preserve = "single", padding = 0) ) + 
     scale_fill_manual(values = colours)
```

[image]

Comment: I fiddled with this option, but I couldn't get it to work with faceted plots---the bars just wouldn't line up.

Answer (score 22):

I had the same problem but was looking for a solution that works with the pipe (`%>%`). Using `tidyr::spread` and `tidyr::gather` from the `tidyverse` does the trick. I use the same data as @Brian Diggs, but with uppercase variable names to not end up with double variable names when transforming to wide:

```
library(tidyverse)

dat <- data.frame(A = rep(LETTERS[1:3], 3),
                  B = rep(letters[1:3], each = 3),
                  V = 1:9)[-2, ]
dat %>% 
  spread(key = B, value = V, fill = NA) %>% # turn data to wide, using fill = NA to generate missing values
  gather(key = B, value = V, -A) %>% # go back to long, with the missings
  ggplot(aes(x = A, y = V, fill = B)) +
  geom_col(position = position_dodge())
```

**Edit:**

There actually is a even simpler solution to that problem in combination with the pipe. Use `tidyr::complete` gives the same result in one line:

```
dat %>% 
  complete(A, B) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = A, y = V, fill = B)) +
  geom_col(position = position_dodge())
```

Comment: Very nice answer, I had no idea `tidyr::complete` existed.

Comment: Awesome idea with tidyr::complete!