# Consistent box width with missing values in a ggplot box plot

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2, na

In ggplot2, I want my boxes in a box plot to be of equal width even when a given level combination does not exist.

For example, in mtcars, cyl=8 and gear=4 does not exist, which leads to larger bars in this plot:

```
qplot(data=mtcars, x=as.factor(cyl), y=mpg,
      colour=as.factor(gear), geom="boxplot")
```

[image]

For a bar plot, padding our data frame with NA values for these level combinations would solve the problem, but not for box plot:

```
mtcars.fill <- data.frame(cyl=8,gear=4,mpg=NA)
mtcars <- rbind.fill(mtcars,mtcars.fill)

qplot(data=mtcars, x=as.factor(cyl), y=mpg, colour=as.factor(gear), geom="boxplot")

Warning message:
Removed 1 rows containing non-finite values (stat_boxplot).
```

Which leads to the exact same plot.

stat_boxplot has an argument for na values, but it is set to not remove NAs by default:

```
na.rm = FALSE
```

Comment: Agreed!  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15367762/r-ggplot-empty-factor-level is has the answer, though all solutions are quite ugly hacks.

Answer (score 1):

The best I can offer is a work-around using `facet_grid()`. This has the added
benefit that points from a `geom_point()` layer will line up with the boxplots.

```
library(ggplot2)

plot1 = ggplot(mtcars, aes(x=factor(gear), y=mpg, colour=factor(gear))) +
        geom_boxplot(space=0) + 
        facet_grid(. ~ cyl, labeller="label_both")

plot2 = plot1 + geom_point()

library(gridExtra)
ggsave(filename="plots.png", plot=arrangeGrob(plot1, plot2, ncol=2), 
       width=10, height=4, dpi=120)
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for this suggestion.  However, in most of my plots I am already mapping another variable to facet.