# Preventing incosistent spacing/bar widths in geom_bar with many bars

Tags: r, ggplot2

In a bar plot with lots of bars the problem occurs that the spacing between bars and/or the widths of the bars becomes incosistent, also changing with changing the width of the plot.

```
set.seed(23511)
dat <- data.frame(x = 1:540, y = rnorm(540))

library(ggplot2)
ggplot(dat) +
  geom_bar(aes(x = x, y = y), stat = "identity")
```

Is there a way to solve this? I tried playing with `width` and the overall plot size to no avail.

[image]

In response to alistaire's comment here's a screenshot of the first few bars from RStudio. Looking at the first 10 values..

```
    x          y
1   1  0.9450960
2   2  0.9277378
3   3  0.4371033
4   4 -1.0333073
5   5  2.0473397
6   6  0.8174123
7   7  0.4277842
8   8 -0.4336887
9   9  0.2156801
10 10  0.4918345
```

.. to me it clearly looks like for the first 3 positive values there's space between the bars/the bars are narrower than for the second set of 3 positive values where there's no space between the bars/the bars are wider.

[image]

Comment: I'm not convinced the width actually is inconsistent; they're just piling up next to each other, so some look wider or narrower. Each individual bar still appears to be the same width, though.

Comment: It may simply be the effect of finite sized pixels

Comment: @alistaire see my edit, please. Or maybe I've just been staring at the plot for too long? ;)

Comment: @RichardTelford could you elaborate on that please?

Comment: beetroot - does the issue persist if you export the plot, say, to pdf? (iy looks okay when I do that)

Comment: @user20650 no, saving as pdf doesn't solve the problem for me, looks the same as before

Comment: Ah, gotcha, it is a pixel thing. If you call `ggsave` on it with a really high `dpi`, you can get it to the point where there's a thin white line between each bar. A really low `dpi` does the reverse. Your screen happens to be in the middle somewhere.

Comment: @alistaire thanks for the hint with increasing the dpi, will try!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think this is a pixel issue. If the x of a bar goes from 1.5 to 2.7 pixels, it will be one pixel wide, if it goes from 1.9 to 3.1 (same width) it will be 2 pixels wide.

You could do lines instead of bars.

```
 ggplot(data=dat, aes(x=x, y=y)) + 
   geom_segment(aes(xend=x, yend=0), size = 0.6)
```

I think you still sometimes run into pixel issues, but it's maybe easier to control with `size`.

Comment: I like your idea with `geom_segment`! I'll just wait if someone comes up with a solution for `geom_bar` before I'll accept your answer.