# Inconsistent bar spacing in ggplot + geom_bar() with time series data

Tags: r, ggplot2, geom-bar

I'm trying to make a time series plot of weekly Covid cases using a bar chart. However when using ggplot, the plot has really inconsistent (though strangely regular?) spacing between bars and it looks messy. E.g.

```
Date <- seq(as.Date("2017-01-01"), as.Date("2020-01-05"), by = 7)
Cases <- seq(1,20,length.out = 158)
data <- as.data.frame(cbind(dates, values))

ggplot(data = data, aes(x = weeks, y = cases)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity") +
  ggtitle("Why the inconsistent spacing?")
```

[image]

Does anyone have any idea why this might be? Or know of a way I could fix it? Or a different plotting method that would achieve the same thing but without the inconsistent spacing?

Thanks,
Debbie

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Preventing incosistent spacing/bar widths in geom\_bar with many bars](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37547223/preventing-incosistent-spacing-bar-widths-in-geom-bar-with-many-bars)

Comment: (geom_segment works here as suggested in the linked thread, thus I am voting to close as a duplicate)

Comment: you have my upvote nonetheless- however two minor things: you're example is not quite reproducible (check your code again in an empty session, and/or with the `reprex` package) 2) you can use `geom_col` instead of `geom_bar(stat = "identity")` -

Answer (score 1):

It's perhaps not a solution, but a remedy, try plotting with color and fill the same color:

```r
geom_bar(stat = "identity", col="darkgrey", fill="darkgrey") +
```

Comment: ooo.... adding "fill" to my code fixed it for some reason that I dont understand .thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can solve this with geom_segment - it's likely an issue with pixel sizes, as suggested by Richard Telford [in this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37547223/7941188).

```r
library(ggplot2)
Date <- seq(as.Date("2017-01-01"), as.Date("2020-01-05"), by = 7)
Cases <- seq(1,20,length.out = 158)
data <- as.data.frame(cbind(Date, Cases))

ggplot(data = data, aes(x = Date, y = Cases)) +
  geom_segment(aes(xend = Date, y = 0, yend = Cases)) +
  ggtitle("This is a pixel issue")
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2021-04-14 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v1.0.0)</sup>