# ggplot2: same bar widths when saving pdf

Tags: r, ggplot2, bar-chart, geom-col

I want all bars to have the same width.

My code works when not saving it to a pdf:

```
library(ggplot2)

dat <- as.data.frame(mtcars)
# convert rownames to a separate column
dat <- cbind(rownames(dat), data.frame(dat, row.names=NULL))
names(dat)[which(names(dat) == "rownames(dat)")] <- "type"

p <- ggplot(data=dat[1:10,]) +
  geom_col(aes(x = reorder(type, wt), y = wt), position=position_dodge2(width = 0.1, preserve = "single"), width = 0.1) +
  coord_flip()

p
```

But when I try to save the plot in a pdf, then the bars have slightly different widths.

```
pdf(paste0(path_out, 
           "test.pdf"),
    width=10, height=4)

print(p)

dev.off()
```

[image: test picture]

With my real data it is even worse:

[image: test picture 2]

I am using Windows 7 Enterprise. How can I fix this?

Comment: Perhaps related discussion? https://github.com/tidyverse/ggplot2/issues/2047

Comment: @teunbrand I think it's possibly rather something like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37547223/preventing-incosistent-spacing-bar-widths-in-geom-bar-with-many-bars

Comment: @tjebo: yes, the answer of your suggested link fixed it. Thank you very much.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Preventing incosistent spacing/bar widths in geom\_bar with many bars](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37547223/preventing-incosistent-spacing-bar-widths-in-geom-bar-with-many-bars)