# Changing geom_bar widths on ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am making a bar chart showing the percentage of different types of prey items returned to a nest.

My data is as follows:

```
Prey <- c(rep("Bird", 12), rep("Lizard", 3), rep("Invertebrate", 406))  
Type <- c(rep("Unknown bird", 12), rep("Skink", 2), rep("Gecko", 1), 
          rep("Unknown Invertebrate", 170), rep("Beetle", 1), 
          rep("Caterpillar", 3), rep("Grasshopper", 3), rep("Huhu grub", 1),  
          rep("Moth", 34), rep("Praying mantis", 1), rep("Weta", 193))  
Preydata <- data.frame(Prey,Type)  

ggplot(Preydata, aes(x = Prey, y = (..count..)/sum(..count..))) +
                  scale_y_continuous(labels = percent_format()) + 
                  geom_bar(aes(fill = Type), position = "dodge")
```

My graph looks like the plot below.

[image]

I would like all the "type" bar widths to be the same, but when I change the width under `geom_bar` it only changes the width of the "prey" bar. When I try to use the following:

```
ggplot(Preydata, aes(x = as.numeric(interaction(Prey, Type)), 
    y = (..count..)/sum(..count..))) + 
    scale_y_continuous(labels = percent_format()) + 
    geom_bar(aes(fill = Type), position = "dodge")
```

My bars are no longer in the correct order, or grouped by "Prey". Is there any way I can change this?
[image]

Comment: Thank you. That helped, but I am unsure how to keep the plot ordered as before while using the interaction() code.

Comment: From the manual, something like this ``geom_bar(position = position_dodge(preserve = "single"))`` is typically recommended.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By using `table` and `prop.table` to *prepare the data before plotting* it is ensured that *all* possible combinations of `Prey` and `Type` are included. This forces the bars to have the same widths without changing the order of bars.

So, this is an alternative approach to 
[using interaction](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38101512/3817004) or [binding missing combinations](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11020437/3817004) which have been marked as duplicates.

```
Preydata2 <- as.data.frame(prop.table(table(Preydata$Prey, Preydata$Type)))
names(Preydata2) <- c("Prey", "Type", "Freq")

library(ggplot2)
library(scales)
ggplot(Preydata2, aes(x = Prey, y = Freq, fill = Type)) +
  scale_y_continuous(labels = percent_format()) + 
  geom_col(position = "dodge")
```

produces

[image]

### Explanation

`table(Preydata$Prey, Preydata$Type)` creates a contingency table of *all* combinations of `Prey`and `Type`, even those combinations which do not occur in the underlying data:

```
             Beetle Caterpillar Gecko Grasshopper Huhu grub Moth Praying mantis Skink Unknown bird
Bird              0           0     0           0         0    0              0     0           12
Invertebrate      1           3     0           3         1   34              1     0            0
Lizard            0           0     1           0         0    0              0     2            0

             Unknown Invertebrate Weta
Bird                            0    0
Invertebrate                  170  193
Lizard                          0    0
```

`prop.table` turns the counts in fractions. This is the equivalent to `(..count..)/sum(..count..)` in the OP.

The final step of data preparation is to convert the table into a data frame, the format required by `ggplot`, and to rename the columns appropriately.

The plot command is similar to the OP except that

- the already computed `Freq` is used instead of computing  `(..count..)/sum(..count..)` on the fly,
- the `fill` aesthetic has been moved to the initial call to `ggplot()`,
- and `geom_col` is used as short-hand for `geom_bar(stat = "identity")` (new function introduced with version 2.2.0 of `ggplot2`).