# Equalize size of plots placed in juxtaposition by grid.arrange

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2

I gathered three `geom_bar()` plots in one plot by `grid.arrange`:

[image]

I removed the y axis of the two right plots (Q2,Q3) and kept the y axis of Q1 as a common axis. Subsequently, I change `plot.margin` a little bit to obtain a continuous x axis. Although this worked fine, it bugs me that the leftmost plot is smaller than the remaining two plots. I highlighted the difference in size by plotting the y axis again. I tried to fix this by changing `plot.margin` but without success. Is there any way to equalize the size of the three plots?

Comment: simply use `facet_grid` instead of `grid.arrange`

Comment: The plots do have the same width, but the bars on the left have smaller width because there are 3 instead of 2. The solution here might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38101512/the-same-width-of-the-bars-in-geom-barposition-dodge

Comment: did you mean "equalize bar width" instead of "equalize size of plots"?

Comment: the plots do have the same width in total, but the leftmost plot area where the bars are located is smaller than the others because the y axis text crops some width/space. I do not mean the size of the bars themselves.

Comment: Does it help if you combine the plots using patchwork: https://github.com/thomasp85/patchwork

Comment: Give us some data. Then we can help you in more detail.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please read the info about [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and how to give a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269). This will make it much easier for others to help you.

Comment: patchwork actually did the job. Thank you for the suggestion!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The package `patchwork` (https://github.com/thomasp85/patchwork) automatically balances the size of the plots while aggregating the plots