# Fix bar width in facet wrapped barplots ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, bar-chart, geom-bar

Here is an example of my data. I have several different sensor data (Var1) broken up by sensor(Var2). Here's a reproducible data set.

```
var.sens1 <- structure(list(Var1 = structure(c(9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 1L, 2L, 
                                           9L, 9L), 
                                         .Label = c("bathymetry", "current", "deep scattering layer", 
                                                    "frontal data", "imagery", "ocean productivity", 
                                                    "salinity",  "sea surface height", "sea surface temperature",
                                                    "vessel", "wind"), 
                                         class = "factor"), 
                        Var2 = structure(c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 7L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 10L), 
                                         .Label = c("AMSR-E", "AVHRR", "CZCS", "Imager", 
                                                    "IRS-P4 OCM", "MERIS", "MODIS", "not specified", 
                                                    "OCI", "SeaWiFS", 
                                                    "SeaWinds"), class = "factor"), 
                        Freq = c(4L, 37L, 1L, 3L, 20L, 4L, 20L, 26L, 2L)), 
                   row.names = c(9L, 20L, 31L, 42L, 75L, 78L,79L, 86L, 108L), 
                   class = "data.frame")
```

I then use this code to facet wrap (rather than stacked barplot) my data.

```
vp <- ggplot(var.sens1, aes(x=Var2, y=Freq, fill=Var1, label=Freq)) + 
  geom_bar(stat="identity")

vp + facet_wrap( ~ Var1, ncol=3, scales="free_y") +
  coord_flip() +
  theme_light()+
  theme(legend.position="none") +
  xlab("Sensor") + ylab("Frequency")
```

I use scales_y=free to remove any unwanted space in the graph. And get the following plot.

[image]

However, the barwidths are different sizes. Does anyone know how to fix the bar width while facet wrapping? Fixing barwidth in geom_bar doesn't seem to work. Neither does using geom_col with position_dodge2 and preserve as recommended [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38101512/the-same-width-of-the-bars-in-geom-barposition-dodge). See code and image below.

```
vp <- ggplot(var.sens1, aes(x=Var2, y=Freq, fill=Var1, label=Freq)) + 
  geom_col(position = "dodge")

vp + 
facet_grid(~Var1, scales = "free_y")+
coord_flip() +
theme_light()+
theme(legend.position="none") +
xlab("Sensor") + ylab("Frequency")
```

I'd prefer to use facet_wrap over facet grid so I don't have one long series of plots ( I have multiple variables that need plotting in my data set not just the three shown).

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [The same width of the bars in geom\_bar(position = "dodge")](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38101512/the-same-width-of-the-bars-in-geom-barposition-dodge)

Comment: I tried position dodge and it didn't seem to work.

Comment: Why? What's the error message you're getting?

Comment: no error message. just doesn't change the widths so they match. It also uses facet_grid, and I have multiple variables so facet_wrap is more applicable.

Comment: no error message.It changes the widths but then doesn't remove the the empty sensors. See update to question.

Comment: Could you make your problem reproducible by sharing a sample of your data so others can help (please do not use `str()`, `head()` or screenshot)? You can use the [`reprex`](https://reprex.tidyverse.org/articles/articles/magic-reprex.html) and [`datapasta`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/datapasta/vignettes/how-to-datapasta.html) packages to assist you with that. See also [Help me Help you](https://speakerdeck.com/jennybc/reprex-help-me-help-you?slide=5) & [How to make a great R reproducible example?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5963269)

Comment: Thanks. I have added the code for a reproducible sample of my data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use geom_col (position = position_dodge2(preserve = "single"))

```
vp <- ggplot(var.sens1, aes(x=Var2, y=Freq, fill=Var1, label=Freq)) + 
  geom_col(position = position_dodge2(preserve = "single"))

vp + 
  facet_grid(~Var1, scales = "free_y")+
  coord_flip() +
  theme_light()+
  theme(legend.position="none") +
  xlab("Sensor") + ylab("Frequency")
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OB3v5.png)