# plot multiple groupwise means in R

Tags: r, ggplot2

my data looks like the following. I need to create some `lineplot/barplot` for average `val` for each group like, `status` and `category` in the csv file.
**Data in `dput` format.**

```
df <-
structure(list(val = c(4608, 4137, 6507, 5124, 
3608, 34377, 5507, 5624, 4608, 4137, 6507, 5124, 
3608, 3437, 5507, 5507, 5624), status = c("1x", 
"1x", "1x", "2x", "2x", "2x", "2x", "2x", "50xy", 
"50xy", "50xy", "60xy", "60xy", "70xy", "xyz", 
"xyz", "xyz"), category = c("A", "C", "A", "A", 
"A", "B", "B", "C", "B", "C", "A", "B", "C", 
"B", "B", "C", "C")), row.names = c(NA, 
-17L), class = "data.frame")
```

I tried the following code but could not figure out the whole thing.

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(df, aes(x = status, y = val, group = category, color = source)) + 
      geom_smooth(method = "loess")
```

Help to plot them (each group wise, such as plotting mean `val` for each `2x` and `B`) in a single window would be really appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do:

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
df %>%
    group_by(category, status) %>%
    mutate(agg = mean(val)) %>%
    ggplot(., aes(status, agg, fill = category, color=status))+
    geom_col(position = "dodge")
```

Comment: The OP wants to plot the means of groups, not just the values. Also just as shorthand, `geom_col()` is equivalent to `geom_bar(stat = "identity")`

Comment: The bars have uneven widths, the last solution in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11020437/consistent-width-for-geom-bar-in-the-event-of-missing-data/46825844#46825844) solved it for me.

Comment: thank you @YOLO, for the hint, it worked, later I converted into line plots.

Answer (score 2):

This question already has an [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53875032/3817004) which requires to compute the aggregated 
`mean(val)` by `status`, `category` group *beforehand*.

However, `ggplot2` includes *transformations* (or *stats*) which enable us to create the desired plot in one go without utilizing other packages:

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(df, aes(x = status, y = val, group = category, colour = category)) +
  stat_summary(geom = "line", fun.y = "mean")
```

This creates a line plot of the mean values [as requested by the OP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53874882/plot-multiple-groupwise-means-in-r#comment94646761_53875032):

[image]

Alternatively, we can tell `geom_line` to use a summary statistics:

```
ggplot(df, aes(status, val, group = category, colour = category)) +
  geom_line(stat = "summary", fun.y = "mean")
```

which creates the same plot.

`stat_summary()` can also be used to show the original data and the summary statistics combined in one plot:

```
ggplot(df, aes(status, val, group = category, colour = category)) +
  geom_point() +
  stat_summary(geom = "line", fun.y = "mean")
```

[image]

This can help to better understand the structure of the underlying data, e.g., outliers. Please, note the different y scale.