# Preserve location of missing columns in combined bar plot

Tags: r, ggplot2, geom-bar

A very commonly posted issue is to preserve the width of bars when there is a missing column in ggplot (e.g. [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11020437/consistent-width-for-geom-bar-in-the-event-of-missing-data), [2](https://www.aj2duncan.com/blog/missing-data-ggplot2-barplots/). What I need in addition to this fix is to also preserve the relative location of the missing bars (i.e. the gaps should be where the bar would have been).

```
ggplot(mtcars, aes(factor(cyl), fill = factor(gear))) +
  geom_bar(position = position_dodge(preserve = "single"))
```

[image: Results - I can't post images yet]

You'll note that in the group for 8 cylinders (far right) there is a missing column for green (gear=4). `preserve="single"` has corrected the width, but the blue bar (gear=5) has shifted left to fill the void.

How can I prevent this? I want there to be a gap where green would have been.

Thank you for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We get the frequency `count` based on 'cyl', 'gear', expand the data with `complete` to get all the combinations while `fill`ing the count column 'n' with 0 (by default all the columns not mentioned in the `complete` gets NA where there is a missing combination) and then plot with `ggplot`

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(ggplot2)
mtcars %>%
   count(cyl, gear) %>%
   complete(cyl = unique(cyl), gear = unique(gear), 
         fill = list(n = 0)) %>%
   ggplot(aes(factor(cyl), n, fill = factor(gear))) + 
        geom_bar(stat = 'identity', position = 'dodge')
```

Comment: Thank you. I was circling complete but couldn't get it to work. Can you explain what the `fill = list(n = 0)` is doing? I'm getting errors in my long code (your example runs fine) to the effect that variables aren't found. I can post that code, but not the data to run it if needed.

Comment: @Andre  `n` is a column created from the `count` step.  I am just summarising go the frequency based on 'cyl', 'gear'.  IN your post, the summarisation is done automatically in the `ggplot`

Comment: @Andre By default, the `complete` returns NA for all columns that are not used in the expansion.  By specifying `fill = ` it is replacing those NA with value specifiedd

Comment: Thank you - I understand now. I up-voted but it's not visible yet :/